# operator precedence from page132 in K&R

Tags: c, operator-precedence

I'm reading K&R and I got stuck in the following sentence.

> `*p -> str++` increments str after accessing whatever it points to (just like `*s++`)

I agree what it said for `*p -> str++`, but for  `*s++`, it doesn't make any sense to me. I think
`*s++` will access whatever it points to AFTER incrementing s, just like `(*s)++`

Comment: The solution to all this head ache is to simply _not_ mix `++` operators with other operators in the same expression. It is a source of countless bugs and there hardly ever exists a situation where you actually need to mix them. When reading K&R you will pick up a lot of bad practice, I would recommend to treat the book as an ancient relic from the 1970s rather than learning material.

Answer (score 3):

`->` and postfix `++` both have higher [precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than `*`, with left-to-right associativity.

The expression `*p->str++` can be read firstly as `*(p->str)++`, which makes semantically the same as `*s++`, which in turn can be read as `*(s++)`. So yes, the indirection will occur *after* the incrementation (`expr++`), but

> The result of the postfix increment and decrement operators is the value of expr.

Thus,

- `p->str`, or `s`, yields a *modifiable lvalue* appropriate for `++` (a pointer type in this instance).
- `++` (postfix) then increments this value in-place, evaluating to the value  of the expression *before* incrementation.
- `*` performs indirection on this pointer value.

Whereas, `(*s)++` will perform indirection *before* incrementing the resulting value.

Comment: unary operators don't have "associativity" as such -- they apply from the inside out, with the operator closest to the primary expression applying first.  There's really no other way they could apply.

Comment: That is covered in the notes section of the linked page on operator precedence, with specifics about unary affixes and member access operators.

Answer (score 1):

The important thing here is the **return value** of `s++`. You need to recall that the **return value** of `s++` is `s`. So the `*` will dereference the address `s` has **before** the increment.

So the code `*s++` is the equivalent to

```
T* temp = s; \___ These two lines is what s++ is doing
s = s + 1;   /
*temp;
```

i.e. `*s++` reads what `s` points to and increments `s` by one.

Note: To **increment `s` before reading what it points to**, you can do `*++s`.

Answer (score 0):

> I think `*s++` will access whatever it points to AFTER incrementing `s`, just like `(*s)++`

This will increase the pointer by one:

```
*s++;
```

This will increase the dereferenced pointer (that is, what it's pointing at) by one:

```
(*s)++;
```

so, it's not the same thing.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char string[] = "Hello";
    
    char *s1 = string;

    printf("%c\n", *s1++);          // 'H'
    printf("%c\n", *s1);            // 'e'
    printf("%s\n", s1);             // "ello"

    char *s2 = string;

    printf("%c\n", (*s2)++);        // 'H'
    printf("%c\n", *s2);            // 'I'  ('H' + 1 = 'I')
    printf("%s\n", s2);             // "Iello"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I think *s++ will access whatever it points to AFTER incrementing s, just like (*s)++

Nope.  `*s++` is parsed as `*(s++)` - you are dereferencing the *result* of `s++`.  The result of `s++` is the current value of `s`; the side effect of incrementing `s` does not affect the result.  Logically, it works like

```
tmp = s
x = *tmp   // where "x =" represents any operation using the value of *tmp
s = s + 1
```

with the caveat that the last two operations can happen in any order, even simultaneously (interleaved or in parallel if the architecture supports it).

`(*s)++` increments the *result* of `*s` - it's logically equivalent to writing

```
tmp = *s
x = tmp     // same as above
*s = *s + 1
```

with the same caveat as above.